# Flutter DragAndDropGridView number of items preloaded

Tags: android, flutter, drag-and-drop

I'm using the Drag and Drop GridView flutter package to display a set of images selected via the gallery, when it initially loads, it loads the first 20 even though only 8 are visible, the rest load as we scroll down, however on some devices the 20 loaded, could cause the app to crash.

Is there a way to reduce the number of images loaded on the initial build?

We use a FutureBuilder to get the thumbnails of the images.